# Converting an ASCII character to decimal within a generator

Tags: python, string, ascii, generator, bioinformatics

Goal: Parse a fastQ file made up of four lines of strings:

1) an ID line (seqID) and possible comment (comm) on the same line;
2) a DNA or protein sequence (seq);
3) an extra line
4) a quality (qual) sequence where each character corresponds to protein or DNA seq (line2)

Question: How do I convert all characters each of my qual strings using `ord()` ??

What I have tried:
The qual line in the fastQ is a line of strings, and I want to loop through all of them and convert them to decimal format with `ord()` . However, when I run a generator that yields `seqID` `seq` `qual` and `comm`, it seems I can't just throw in `qual = ord(block[3])` where I define these newly parsed variables since I get the following error when I attempt to parse my fastQ file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fast_splitter_v1.py", line 91, in <module>
    for q in split:
  File "fast_splitter_v1.py", line 28, in read_fastq
    seqID, seq, qual = line1[0][1:], block[1], ord(block[3])
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 1550 found
```

I assume this way is attempting to apply `ord()` to all `qual` characters in my file (of which there are 1550 of them).  This seemed like the best way to do it, but now I'm looking for a solution that works.

Here is my code:

```
def read_fastq(f):
    '''reads in fastaq file-like object in conventional 4-line NCBI format and 
    yields a tuple of lists comprising seqID (sequence ID/name/title), 
    seq (sequence), and qual (monomer read quality)'''
    ###CONVERT ALL QUAL SCORES TO INTEGER WITH ORD()
    lines = f.readlines()
    while len(lines) > 3:
        block = [lines.pop(0)[:-1] for z in range(4)]
        line1 = block[0].split(' ', 1)
        if len(line1) ==2:
            comm = line1[1]
        else:
            comm = ''
        seqID, seq, qual = line1[0][1:], block[1], block[3]
        yield seqID, seq, qual, comm
```

Question summary:

With the above code, how can I convert everything in qual from ASCII to decimal format with `ord()` and keep my generator function?

Sample FastQ:

```
`@SEQ_ID
GATTTGGGGTTCAAAGCAGTATCGATCAAATAGTAAATCCATTTGTTCAACTCACAGTTT
 +
 !''*((((***+))%%%++)(%%%%).1***-+*''))**55CCF>>>>>>CCCCCCC65`
```

Comment: post few records from the file to illustrate the inputs

Comment: @Maria Zverina I'll post a sample fastQ in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm probably still not understanding the question but what's there to stop you from doing final line as follows:

```
yield seqID, seq, map(ord, qual), comm
```

OR

```
yield seqID, seq, [ord(c) for c in qual], comm
```

Comment: both of these suggestions worked, but it constructed a list of quality scores within my tuple.  If I wanted to later "trim" both my sequences and quality scores at some minimum quality score, then would I have to also convert my sequences to a list of strings to map them to eachother?  EG: `(@SEQID, ['G','A','T'...], [33, 39, 39...]`